# Dynamic Arrays not properly initializing

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic, mergesort

I am writing a program that uses two dynamic arrays to sort the original array: One for the left side, and one for the right side.

However, the dynamic arrays do not receive the original array in lines 23 and 28 (As demonstrated by the cout methods throughout the array). They are either empty, or contain elements that are out of bounds. Thus, the program does not work as a whole. My question is then, is the issue with the initialization itself, or is it with the declaration on lines 18-19? I personally believe it is with the declaration, but I am unsure of what I should do with it, as with a Dynamic Array, I do not want to mess with the size too much. I included all of the methods for proper testing, but I will edit this question if they are deemed unnecessary. Thank you in advance for your help.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void Merge(int *array, int left, int middle, int right)
{
int * LArray;
int * RArray;
int counter = left;//This counter is used as a marker for the main array.
int mid = middle;

cout<<"Left " << left << "middle: "<< middle << " right: " << right<<endl;

LArray = new int[middle-left + 1];
RArray = new int[right];

/*Initializes LArray*/
for (int i = left; i < middle - left + 1; i++)
{
    LArray[i] = array[i];
}

/*Initializes RArray*/
int temp = 0;
for (int i = middle; i < right; i++)
{
    RArray[temp] = array[i];
    temp++;
}

/*Prints out LArray*/
cout<<"LARRAY: ";
for (int i = left; i < middle- left + 1; i++)
{
    cout<<LArray[i]<< " ";
}

/*Prints out RArray*/
cout<<endl<<"RARRY: ";
temp = 0;
for (int i = middle; i < right; i++)
{
    temp = 0;
    cout<<RArray[temp]<< " ";
    temp++;
}
cout<<endl;

while (left <= middle && mid <= right)
{
    /*This if statement checks if the number in the left array is smaller than the number in the right array*/
    if (LArray[left] < RArray[right])
    {
        array[counter] = LArray[left];
        left++;
        counter++;
        cout<<"First if: array[counter]: "<< array[counter]<<" LArray[left]" << LArray[left]<<" left: "<< left<<" counter : "<< counter<<endl;
    }
    /*This else statement checks if the number in the right array is smaller than the number in the left array*/
    else
    {
        array[counter] = RArray[right];
        mid++;
        counter++;
        cout<<"    First else: array[counter]: "<< array[counter] <<  " RArray[right] "<< RArray[right]<<" mid: "<< mid<<" counter : "<< counter<<endl;
    }
}
/*If RArray is completed, check this one for any remaining elements.*/
while (left <= middle)
{
    array[counter] = LArray[left];
    left++;
    counter++;
    cout<<" First while: array[counter]: "<< array[counter]<<" LArray[left]" << LArray[left]<<" left: "<< left<<" counter : "<< counter<<endl;
}

/*If LArray is completed, check this one for any remaining elements.*/
while (mid <= right)
{
    array[counter] = RArray[right];
    mid++;
    counter++;
    cout<<"  Second while: array[counter]: "<< array[counter] <<  " RArray[right] "<< RArray[right]<<" mid: "<< mid<<" counter : "<< counter<<endl;
}

delete [] LArray;
delete [] RArray;

}


void MergeSort( int *array,int left, int right ) 
{ 
if ( left < right ) 
{ 
    int middle = ( left + right ) / 2;
    MergeSort( array, left, middle ); 
    MergeSort( array, middle + 1, right ); 
    Merge( array, left, middle, right ); 
} 
};

/*Checks if the array listed is sorted by looping through and checking if the current number is smaller than the previous.*/
bool IsSorted(int* array, unsigned long long size)
{

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    cout<<array[i]<< " ";
}
cout<<endl;
for (int i = 1; i < size; i++)
{
    if (array[i] < array[i-1])
        return false;
}
return true;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
int array[8] = {5, 2, 4, 7, 1, 3, 2, 6};
MergeSort(array, 0, 8);

bool check = IsSorted(array, 8);

if (check)
    cout<<"It is sorted!";
else
    cout<<"It is not sorted!";
return 0;
}
```

Comment: is there a reason why you can't use `std::vector`?

Comment: @Massa Well, he taught us MergeSort using two arrays, so that is how I  originally created it; however, since I was unsure of whether or not he would be okay with it, I have emailed him. Assuming he is okay with it, may you please explain how it would help? I apologize if that is a stupid question, but I am not too familiar with std::vector.

Comment: Look [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). `std::vector` is just a fancy, dynamically-allocated and dynamically-sized array. It would  help not having to worry about allocating and deallocating the arrays `LArray` and `RArray` -- but on a second look, this does not seem to be your problem... I'll take a look on it tomorrow morning, if nobody else has answered by then!

Answer (score 1):

The idea of merge sort is that you recursively split an array into two halves, sort those two halves and then merge them back together.

Here are the things I see wrong with your code:

Code weirdness that aren't the problem with your algorithm:

Your left array is always larger than necessary, since you're allocating it to have **middle** elements and initializing it as such.

You initialize right array twice.

The actual problems with your algorithm:

You're not initializing counter correctly, it's always being set as 0 so no matter how deep you are in the callstack, you are always setting elements 0 through **middle** to be the sorted array instead of the range between left and right.

You're trying to index into the right array with argument **right** ...which will always be large than the number of elements in right array since you allocated it to have **right - middle** elements.

You also have an error in your MergeSort function. You are never actually sorting the **middle** element since in the Merge function **array[right]** is never added to **RArray**, so the first recursive call won't sort it, and you're passing in **middle + 1** to the second recursive call so it's not sorting it.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my errors. The MergeSort sorts fine now, it's just now it is still giving me extremely large positive and negative numbers, a sign that it is still going out of bounds.

Here's the thing, though- It may be me sounding like an idiot right now, but as I have my code now (and am going to update the above code to reflect what you told me), the RArray is consistently empty, which, when called, leads it to give out the high numbers. It usually is not even initialized because right-middle usually equals 0. Do you think I should initialize RArray with just right?

Comment: So the size of LArray is now correct but size of RArray is incorrect! In practice, if you're using a derived value multiple times (such as **middle - left + 1**), you should save it off in a variable so you don't have to do the calculation every time. You should also be making sure neither LArray or RArray are size zero. Trying to allocate zero elements in array is going to lead you into trouble.

You're initializing LArray wrong, you will in general put values into it past its bounds. The way you initialize RArray is correct.

Comment: Your while loops are also still incorrect. LArray and RArray are both smaller than array so you can not use **left** and **right** to index into them. Like when you initialize RArray, use a different variable that starts from zero.

Comment: Also in MergeSort, as I said in the initial comment, adding +1 to middle will leave values unsorted.